# How to move a node using Hpricot

Tags: html, ruby, hpricot

I am using Hpricot to select a `<div>` element from a web page:

```
doc = open("overview.html") { |f| Hpricot(f) }
puts doc.search("div[@class=leftnav-btn]")
```

I want to copy that element and paste it to under other `<div>` element with `class="secondDiv"`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hpricot is deprecated, and the site says "Hpricot has ended. Please consider an alternative like nokogiri.". Nokogiri implements some hpricot-isms, but in general we don't use them. Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum HTML that demonstrates the problem, along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

div1 = doc.at('div.leftnav-btn').remove
doc.at('div.secondDiv').add_next_sibling(div1)
puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <body>
# >>     
# >>     <div class="secondDiv"></div>
# >> <div class="leftnav-btn">foo</div>
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

The empty line after `<body>` is the result of the trailing TextNode that follows the `<div>` tag. It doesn't affect how XML works, nor does it affect the data, it's only cosmetic.

```
doc.at('.leftnav-btn').next.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Text
doc.at('.leftnav-btn').next.to_html # => "\n    "
```

Notice that in the above selector I'm only using the class `.leftnav-btn` since it wasn't necessary to use the full `div.leftnav-btn`. Nokogiri, like Hpricot, uses CSS selectors, and also allows XPath, making for more flexibility. Nokogiri also supports `%` and `/` though we don't use them:

```
(doc % '.leftnav-btn').next.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Text
(doc % '.leftnav-btn').next.to_html # => "\n    "
```

Hpricot was deprecated a long time ago, and shouldn't be used. Nokogiri is the standard for HTML/XML parsing for Ruby.

The Nokogiri tutorials cover the basics so spend some time with them. See the documentation for [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) and [Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) for more information.